# How to set swagger config properties from config file

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I am using Azure API Management to host three versions of an API - dev, qa, stage. These are basically three different build configurations of the api, so when imported to APIM - "MyAPI-dev", "MyAPI-qa", "MyAPI-stage".

I am using swagger for documentation. When I trigger a revision in Terraform to build/re-create the API definitions, i am getting error:

```
"my-ApiM-dev" / Resource Group "rg-myApim"): apimanagement.APIClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending 
request: StatusCode=409 -- Original Error: Code="IdentifierAlreadyInUse" Message="Resource already exists."
```

I am 99% sure this is due to the "title" in `SwaggerConfig.cs` file, it is the same value for all configurations. Thus deploying two of the APIs with the same title is throwing the error.

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
  .EnableSwagger(c =>
    {
      c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "MyApiTitle");
    }
```

How can I get the title to be unique based on the configuration?

I tried creating config values in web.config value for each configuration and referencing the key in the config file, but it didn't work, SwaggerUi picked up the default value in web.config file only.

web.dev.config:

```
<add key="BuildConfig" value="dev" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>
```

SwaggerConfig.cs:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
    .EnableSwagger(c =>
    {
        c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "MyApiTitle-" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BuildConfig"]);
    }
```

Another option is to script deleting the API, import the API and rename the title, but I would do that as a last resort.

Would like to do this dynamically in the project code though.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to achieve this with PowerShell, please check if that helps to you

https://medium.com/@rakesh.suryawanshi/deploy-azure-web-api-into-azure-api-management-with-powershell-3d14d1610b07

also, check if you are able to deploy it manually with your approach.